# How can I async await multiple asynchronous MongoDB findOne functions with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise

I am using "await" on multiple MongoDB ".findOne" functions to different collections one at a time. I would like to let them all run asynchronously together and somehow know when they are all ready to use.

Instead of doing this:

```
async function myFunction() {
    const collection_1 = await firstCollection.findOne({})
    const collection_2 = await secondCollection.findOne({})
    const collection_3 = await thirdCollection.findOne({})

    console.log(collection_1, collection_2, collection_3)
  }
```

Can I do something like this?

```
async function myFunction() {
    [collection_1, collection_2, collection_3]
    
    await new Promise(() => {
      collection_1 = firstCollection.findOne({})
      collection_2 = secondCollection.findOne({})
      collection_3 = thirdCollection.findOne({})
    })

    console.log(collection_1, collection_2, collection_3)
  }
```

I don't know how to correctly use Promises to do this.

Comment: How about using Promise.all or promise.allsettled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tracking the parallel execution of multiple promise-based asynchronous operations, use `Promise.all()`:

```
async function myFunction() {
    const [collection_1, collection_2, collection_3] = await Promise.all([
        firstCollection.findOne({}), 
        secondCollection.findOne({}), 
        thirdCollection.findOne({})
    ]);
    console.log(collection_1, collection_2, collection_3)
}
```

`Promise.all()` will reject if any of the promises you pass it reject.  If you want all results, regardless of whether one might reject, you can use `Promise.allSettled()` instead.  See the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) for exactly how its resolved value works.